# Interpolation of sin/cos

Tags: trigonometry, linear-programming

I am trying to optimize sin/cos for my MCU in order to calculate geo distance. This part of formula particularly is using trigonometry:

```
double e = (MyTan( lat2 / 2 + quarter_pi ) / MyTan( lat1 / 2 + quarter_pi ));
```

So I tried to build my own `sin/cos` lookup tables for `-PI` to `PI` as follows:

```
#define PARTPERDEGREE 10
double mysinlut[PARTPERDEGREE * 90 + 1];
double mycoslut[PARTPERDEGREE * 90 + 1];
void MySinCosCreate()
{
    int i;
    double angle, angleinc;

    // Each degree also divided into 10 parts
    angleinc = (M_PI / 180) / PARTPERDEGREE;
    for (i = 0, angle = 0.0; i <= (PARTPERDEGREE * 90 + 1); ++i, angle += angleinc)
    {
        mysinlut[i] = sin(angle);
    }

    angleinc = (M_PI / 180) / PARTPERDEGREE;
    for (i = 0, angle = 0.0; i <= (PARTPERDEGREE * 90 + 1); ++i, angle += angleinc)
    {
        mycoslut[i] = cos(angle);
    }
}



double MySin(double rad)
{
   int ix;
   int sign = 1;


   if(rad > (M_PI / 2))
        rad = M_PI / 2 - (rad - M_PI / 2);

   if(rad < -(M_PI / 2))
       rad = -M_PI / 2 - (rad + M_PI / 2);

   if(rad < 0)
   {
        sign = -1;
        rad *= -1;
   }

   ix = (rad * 180) / M_PI * PARTPERDEGREE;

   return sign * mysinlut[ix];
}

double MyCos(double rad)
{
   int ix;
   int sign = 1;


    if(rad > M_PI / 2)
    {
        rad = M_PI / 2 - (rad - M_PI / 2);
        sign = -1;
    }
    else if(rad < -(M_PI / 2))
    {
        rad = M_PI / 2 + (rad + M_PI / 2);
        sign = -1;
    }
    else if(rad > -M_PI / 2 && rad < M_PI / 2)
    {   
        rad = abs(rad);
        sign = 1;
    }

    ix = (rad * 180) / M_PI * PARTPERDEGREE;

    return sign * mycoslut[ix];
}

double MyTan(double rad)
{
    return MySin(rad) / MyCos(rad);
}
```

You can see the resolution of table is 10 parts per degree. I can increase it little, but it doesn't help much and it looks like I need some interpolation. Could anyone suggest some practical improvements to my functions to have better results? Below is graph of 234 different results of the `e`. Blue series are with ideal sin/cos and red are from LUT.

[image]

Comment: Have you had a look into [CORDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC)?

Comment: Yes, but the math is way too complex for me in order to implement. Haven't seen any simple implementation in C.

Answer (score 1):

Good rational approximations for $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ on $[0, \pi/4]$ are

```
-.41498e-8+(1.000000515+(-.105463955e-4+(-.1665856017+(-.297181298e-3
 +(.8894256955e-2-.5282205803e-3*x)*x)*x)*x)*x)*x
```

and

```
1.000000002+(-.2053e-6+(-.4999959817+(-.2922839e-4+(.4176577023e-1
+(-.163891331e-3-.1275240287e-2*x)*x)*x)*x)*x)*x
```

with maximum absolute errors approximately $.415 \times 10^{-8}$ and $.2 \times 10^{-8}$ respectively.  You can use these to calculate $\sin(x)$ or $\cos(x)$ for any $x$: e.g. if $\pi/4 \le x \le \pi/2$ then $\sin(x) = \cos(\pi/2 - x)$ and $\cos(x) = \sin(\pi/2-x)$.